# How to hide media uploads by other users in the Media manager

Tags: wordpress

i am using wordpress multisite and wan to hide medea which others have uploaded. Like if X User of that site have uploaded any media in the wordpress, Y User should not be able to see or access this from there login. Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
/**
 * Allow access to own content only
 */
function my_authored_content($query) {

//get current user info to see if they are allowed to access ANY posts and pages
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// set current user to $is_user
$is_user = $current_user->user_login;

//if is admin or 'is_user' does not equal #username
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    //if in the admin panel
    if($query->is_admin) {

        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);

    }
    return $query;
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_authored_content');
```

This will only let admin and the author see the content.

You can either add it to the main functions file or turn it into a plugin.

Comment: Thanks, it awesome :) , its working perfectly fine. I am new in wp, if possible can you guide how can i make this as  plugin.

Answer (score 2):

To create it as a plugin:

1. Create a new file
2. add the code from here: http://pastebin.com/rfMLM0BU
3. save it as my-authored-content.php
4. upload it to your plugins directory.

Hope this helps you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me works this:

```
function mymo_parse_query_useronly( $wp_query ) {
  if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['post_type']) && $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'attachment'){
    if ( !current_user_can( 'level_5' ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
    }
  }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'mymo_parse_query_useronly' );
```

I use this for uploaded profile picture for the user profile in front end